# Controller being lost in actions

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember.js application running on top of a rails app. this ember application has a map and a view to handle a marker.

Every time i change routes I have to destroy the marker inside this view. The problem is: when I enter the `generateMarker` for the first time I get my controller (`this.get("controller")`) and later on my `dropend` observer I can get it with another `this.get("controller")`

But when I change routes and come back the `generateMarker` is able to get controller but the `updateLocation` can't. Why?

First run:

```
generateMarker: ->
    $controller = @get("controller")
    # $controller gets the object
```

Then I invoque:

```
  updateLocation: (lat, lon, animate = true) ->
      ...
      @get("controller").center_passageiro()
      # This also works.
```

Then I move to another route and come back, this time:

```
generateMarker: ->
    $controller = @get("controller")
    # $controller gets the object and read valid information
```

But then:

```
  updateLocation: (lat, lon, animate = true) ->
      ...
      @get("controller").center_passageiro()
      # This gives me this error: Cannot call method 'center_passageiro' of null
      # And inspecting it i see that this.get('controller') is now returning null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the entire class (using coffeescript)

```
Webapp.ChamadaMarkerView = Ember.View.extend

  generateMarker: ->
    $controller = @get("controller")
    unless Webapp.chamadaMarker?
      Webapp.chamadaMarker = @

    if $controller.get("mlat") isnt null && $controller.get("mlon") isnt null
      lat = $controller.get("mlat")
      lon = $controller.get("mlon")
    else
      lat = $controller.get("lat")
      lon = $controller.get("lon")

    @set("marker", new google.maps.Marker
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
      map: window.map
      draggable: ($controller.get("nodrag") isnt null)
      animation: google.maps.Animation.Drop
      icon:"/assets/icone_passageiro.png"
    )

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(@get("marker")
    , "dragend"
    , ->
      pos = Webapp.chamadaMarker.get("marker").getPosition()
      $controller.updatePosMarker(pos.lat(), pos.lng())
      Webapp.chamadaMarker.updateLocation(pos.lat(), pos.lng())
    )

  updateLocation: (lat, lon, animate = true) ->
    mk = @get("marker")
    mk.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon))
    if animate
      mk.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP)
      @get("controller").center_passageiro()

  didInsertElement: ->
    @generateMarker()

  willDestroyElement: ->
    @get("marker").setMap(null)
```

**EDIT**

My routes

```
Webapp.Router.map ->
  @route 'MapEmEspera', path: '/'
  @route 'MapEmChamada', path: '/mapa'
  @route 'cadastro', path: '/dados'
  @route 'novo_cadastro', path: '/cadastrar'
  @route 'chamada', path: '/chamar'
  @route 'espera', path: '/aguardando'
  @route 'taxista', path: '/taxista'
```

Comment: how do your routes look like?

Comment: added my routes, check my edit

Comment: one more thing :) can you actually show the controller or where it's model get's set? I mean the controller that backs up the `ChamadaMarkerView`

Comment: My ``ChamadaMarkerView`` is being set on the template of 2 different controllers ``MapChamada`` and ``MapEspera``, i'm using ``{{view ChamadaMarkerView}}`` to render

Comment: where does `updateLocation` get called and how?

Comment: ``updateLocation`` is called in the ``dragend`` event, but i found my problem, it was on the generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find my problem

```
generateMarker: -> # A generate method because I should create a global object
  $controller = @get("controller")
  unless Webapp.chamadaMarker? # if this object is already created ignore it
    Webapp.chamadaMarker = @
```

but this gives me a problem every time this object is destroyed, `ember.js` will almost never set a object to `null`, this way every time i change the controller i get a new view, but the global object is not updated.

to fix it i just add this lines:

```
geraMarker: ->
  $controller = @get("controller")
  if Webapp.chamadaMarker?
    Webapp.chamadaMarker = null
  Webapp.chamadaMarker = @
```

and now its working fine